# Как вывести матрицу без последнего столбца, без true или false

Tags: java

Задача: /*
Дана целочисленная матрица размера MxN, заполненная случайными значениями в диапазоне от -99 до 99.
Удалить её последний столбец, содержащий только отрицательное элементы. Если требуемых столбцов нет,
то вывести матрицу без изменений.
*/

```
import java.util.Random;
public class proga4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int M=4;
        int N=5;
        int [][] a = create(M, N);}
        //void print(a);

    static int [][] create(int sz1, int sz2)//Создаём структуру матрицы
     {
    int [][] b;
    b = new int [sz1][];
    for (int i =0; i < sz1; i++)
    b[i] = new int[sz2];
    return b;
    }
    static void init(int [][] b) { //Заполняем таблицу рандомными цифрами от -99 до 99
        Random obj = new Random();
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i< b.length; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<b[0].length; j++)
        b[i][j] = obj.nextInt() % 100;
        }

    static void init1(int [][] b) {
        int i, j, cnt = 0;
        for (i = 0;i<(M-1);i++) {
        if(a[i][N-1]<0) {
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }
        }
        if(cnt == N) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (M-1).length; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        else {

                }
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO это не бюро переводов.

Comment: Ну или помогите с решением данной задачи: Дана целочисленная матрица размера MxN, заполненная случайными значениями в диапазоне от -99 до 99.
Удалить её последний столбец, содержащий только отрицательное элементы. Если требуемых столбцов нет,
то вывести матрицу без изменений.

Comment: помочь можно когда человек начал и столкнулся с какой либо проблемой, в вашем же случае это "напишите за меня", что так же тут не приветствуется.

Comment: Хорошо, я поправил. Я остановился, на этом шаге

Answer (score 2):

Дана матрица `int[][] a` с колонками `columns` и строками `rows`.

Проверяем последний столбец

```
// Индекс последнего столбца:
int lastCol = columns -1;
// Сигнал о том, что в столбце есть хотя бы один положительный элемент
bool positiveflag = false;
// Бежим по строкам
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    if( a[i][lastCol] > 0 ) {
        positiveFlag = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Выводим полученный результат, или копируем матрицу:

```
// Если флаг, значит просто выводим матрицу как есть
// иначе копируем ее в другую матрицу без посделнего столбца
if( positiveFlag ) {
    // выводим
} else {
    int[][] b = create(rows, columns -1); // <- Убрали последний столбец
    for(int row = 0; row < b.length; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < b[row].length; col++) {
            b[row][col] = a[row][col];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Код у вас странный конечно.
1. я не прочитал нормы поведения, так что извиняюсь за свой французский.
2. Собственно не увидел у вас места где вы заполняете массив отрицательными символами????
3. Как я понял по условию ,если в последнем столбце матрицы только отрицательные значения то их выводить не нужно!

Собственно используя эти условия все сводится банально к 3 методам.
1.генерация массива

```
public void generateArr (int _row , int _column) {
    //объявляем ваши данные
    //создаем цикл
    //создаем случайное число от (-99 до 99) а не как у вас только положительно
    //заполняем значениями массив
}
```

2.Проверяем все ли числа в последнем столбце отрицательные

```
public boolean isAllNumberInLastColumnBelowZero (int[][] _arr) {
    //берем массив и проверяем только последнюю его колонку на соответствие условию
    // если условие выполнено то возвращаем true иначе false
}
```

3. Ну а далее выводим наш массив, с учетом выполненной проверки

```
public void printingArr (int[][] arr, boolean _isAllNumberInLastColumnBelowZero) {
    //теперь у нас есть все что бы распечатать наш массив
    //В зависимости от _isAllNumberInLastColumnBelowZero просто либо будем либо
    //не будем выводит на печать последнюю колонну.
}
```

Думаю это более чем достаточно для решения вашей задачи, если вам это не поможет, то вам стоит начать с азов.